# Liferay 6.2 Lucene replication in cluster

Tags: lucene, liferay, cluster-computing, liferay-6, liferay-6.2

I'd welcome any help regarding simple issue: I have clustered environment and I enabled Lucene replication in properties (`lucene.replicate.write=true`). Now, all the tutorials are instructing me to reindex Lucene.

**Should I run it on one node? On both? Simultaneously or sequentially?**

This question has been asked in Liferay Forum as well: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/69175435.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what I did at first was following:

- `cluster.link.enabled=true`
- `lucene.replicate.write=true`

and the result was **NOT WORKING** replication.

What I tried next was to overcome this issue and continue with clustering the rest of the portal which at the end helped lucene as well. My progress was to:

- deploy cluster activation keys
- deploy ehcache-cluster-web.war
- portal-ext.properties:

  - `cluster.link.enabled=true`
  - `cluster.link.autodetect.address=<COMMONLY_ACCESSIBLE_IP_AND_PORT>`
  - `lucene.commit.batch.size=1`
  - `lucene.commit.time.interval=5000`
  - `lucene.replicate.write=true`
  - `ehcache.cluster.link.replication.enabled=true`
  - `cluster.link.channel.properties.control=<PATH_TO_XML>`
  - `cluster.link.channel.properties.transport.0=<PATH_TO_XML>`
  - `portal.instance.protocol=http`
  - `portal.instance.http.port=8080`
- setenv.sh

  - `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`
  - `-Djgroups.bind_addr=<IP_OF_THE_NODE>`
- edit clusterlink_control and clusterlink_transport files by Liferay tutorials
- when servers shutted down delete contents of data/lucene and in Control Panel run reindaxation on one node

At the end, Lucene replication **IS WORKING**. What I think could be significant is following. At first, portal.properties explanation on keys `lucene.commit.*` is kind of hard to comprehend. By trial and error I found out that these two keys are in AND relation. Also, I found out about `portal.instance.*` keys which are used for multiple purposes in clustering and can matter if you have loadbalancers and/or Apaches between the nodes and autodetect fails.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to configure search clustering in Liferay. If you use the `lucene.replicate.write=true` way, you're looking at several reindexing runs: On every restart of a server you must reindex that server's documents, as it might have missed indexing requests when it was down.

So, short answer: Don't worry, reindex both. Sooner or later you'll do it anyways, no matter if you need only one now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Olaf! I have to admit that I also posted this question on Liferay forum, where I've got slightly different answer: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/69175435. According to Amos, each node sync itself on start, but you say that replication works only when both servers are UP when the change to index is happening. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Please link your other post to this one as well (and read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823). With both these answers it should be simple to try it out yourself. I'm rather safe than sorry and switch on "reindex on startup". It might be that this is old knowledge and is not necessary any more. If Amos claims that the index will be synced, he's probably right. But you should easily be able to test it. Watch the log files when you restart. And try if search works after you've changed something on server A while server B was down.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right about the posting. I've added cross-links to both sites. I will surely test the replication. The reason why I was asking was simply to be sure when writing release instructions. Going to production with information how it works directly from Liferay and taking is as a fact seems more safe. :)